# Meteor JS: How to display only data that have certain words in Mongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

For example i have

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
```

And i insert in my posts some data like this

```
Posts.insert({
   tags: ["444","555"]
});


Posts.insert({
   tags: ["111","222"]
});


Posts.insert({
   tags: ["111","333"]
});
```

Now i want to show **Posts** that have in **tags** numbers **111** (String).

**Question:**  How i can do this ?

Comment: Your question is good but could be made better. You don't need to salute us (well, "Hey" is fine, but if one of your posts is edited by someone else it will probably be removed), it's considered noise because we want to focus 120% on the question. Also, when you ask how to do something, you should always include your attempts and/or research. As an example, you could tell us which [mongo operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) you tried and how they didn't work. This is because some users only consider SO as a "free code service", we have higher standards than that!

Comment: Thanks for making the question more clear. Now you only need to add research and/or attempts, and the question will be a perfect fit!

Comment: Also helps to capitalize "I" properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Post.find({
  tags: "111"
});
```

I believe this should do fine.

Comment: Reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#array-element-equals-a-value.